# Global lock being ignored?

Tags: python, locking

I'm using the `SimpleHTTPServer` as a proxy. Oversimplified, my program looks like this:

```
print_lock = Lock()

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        displayABC()
        displayDEF()

    def do_POST(self):
        displayABC()

def displayABC():
    print_lock.acquire()

    print "A"
    print "B"
    print "C"

    print_lock.release()

def displayDEF():
    print_lock.acquire()

    print "D"
    print "E"
    print "F"

    print_lock.release()

httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', 80), Proxy)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Because many requests are coming in very fast, the `display` methods overlap between requests, ie:

```
A
D   # -> Note that they are 'out of order' in the output
E
F
B
C
...
```

When I would ideally like all the prints in the same method to follow each other:

```
A
B   # -> Correct order
C
D
E
F
...
```

You can see in the code that I tried to use a `Lock()`, this had no effect. I search SO and there are some similar questions but they all deal with threads.

Comment: Its your forking server (hee, hee). Since it forks, the locks are in different processes.

Comment: multiprocessing.Lock may fix things.